# cocos2d move an object along a path with constant velocity

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for a method to move an object along a path with constant velocity,like a car racing on a track. I tried ccActionBezier and ccActionCardinalSpline, but I can't keep the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

CCActions over time have durations, because of that you would have to scale your duration to the distance you want to go.  Another option is to roll your own by using the -(void)update:(CCTime)delta method.

Answer (score 0):

if you know start and end points, you can get constant velocity from this method

```
- (CGFloat)calculateVelocity:(CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end speed:(CGFloat)speed
{
    return ccpDistance(start, end) / speed;
}
```